# OS X - Can anyone explain why I was getting an OS error in my .pythonrc.py file after installing ipython3 or give me a more robust solution than this?

Tags: macos, python-3.x, ipython

I installed ipython3 using pip3.

```
pip3 install ipython[all]
```

When I ran python it was encountering an error (only on Python 3 not on Python 2) from my ~/.pythonrc.py file.

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Mike/.pythonrc.py", line 43, in <module>
    readline.read_history_file(history_path)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I couldn't find an answer on stackoverflow but did some digging and found a solution. I'm not sure why this works now or if there's a better solution.

In the .pythonrc.py file:

```
try:
   import readline
except ImportError:
   pass

history_path = os.path.expanduser('~/.pyhistory')
if os.path.isfile(history_path):
   readline.read_history_file(history_path)
atexit.register(lambda x=history_path: readline.write_history_file(x))
```

The solution was to import gnureadline instead:

```
try:
   import gnureadline as readline
except ImportError:
   pass
```

Can anyone tell me if there is a more robust solution or why this happened in the first place?

Answer (score 8):

I just found the answer:

```py
import gnureadline as readline
```

Based on the link:

[gnureadline for IPython OSX](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/install/install.html#readline)

> On OSX, if you are using the built-in Python shipped by Apple, you
>   will be missing a proper readline implementation as Apple ships
>   instead a library called libedit that provides only some of readline’s
>   functionality. While you may find libedit sufficient, we have
>   occasional reports of bugs with it and several developers who use OS X
>   as their main environment consider libedit unacceptable for
>   productive, regular use with IPython.
>
> Therefore, IPython on OS X depends on the gnureadline module. We will
>   not consider completion/history problems to be bugs for IPython if you
>   are using libedit.