# python readline module giving PermissionError: [Errno 1] only when run at startup

Tags: python, readline, permission-denied

I'm making a console based game that saves input history, to help with debugging I created a function that will automatically input commands on start

```
def __readfile (self) -> None:
    lines = None
    with open("insts.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.read().split("\n")
    if (lines == None):
        print("attempted to read insts.txt for instructions, could not find file")
        return
    self.__initfile = True
    for line in lines:
        self.parse_input(line)
    self.__initfile = False
```

in the instance of the error "self.parse_input" ultimately leads to "readline.read_history_file" and none of the code in between the two has any effect on the error

but it gives this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    game.start()
  File "/Users/tristans/Documents/GitHub/console-rpg/classes.py", line 1353, in start
    self.__readfile()
  File "/Users/tristans/Documents/GitHub/console-rpg/classes.py", line 1345, in __readfile
    self.parse_input(line)
  File "/Users/tristans/Documents/GitHub/console-rpg/classes.py", line 1223, in parse_input
    self._parse_dialog(text)
  File "/Users/tristans/Documents/GitHub/console-rpg/classes.py", line 1128, in _parse_dialog
    self._parse_dialog("leave")
  File "/Users/tristans/Documents/GitHub/console-rpg/classes.py", line 1101, in _parse_dialog
    self._load_hist_scope()
  File "/Users/tristans/Documents/GitHub/console-rpg/classes.py", line 1331, in _load_hist_scope
    readline.read_history_file("history.txt")
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

I have looked everywhere for an answer to where this error is coming from and can't find one

I've tried changing the file read operation from the "with open("insts.txt")" to a hardcoded list but that didn't work, os.access("history.txt", os.R_OK) also returns true when called just before "readline.read_history_file"

Comment: Does it help?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58479686/permissionerror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted-after-macos-catalina-update

Comment: @Kamel I've actually already looked at that question and found it wasn't helpful as this error only occurs when I call read_history_file and not during any other file operations I'm doing

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a Mac-specific issue with readline. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29572581/566307), you need to use gnureadline on the Mac, rather than readline.

```
import gnureadline as readline
```